# Problem saving file to network folder when receiving the file through lan - Golang

Tags: go, server, nfs

Probably a confusing title.Let me explain

I have a Go server.Users can upload photos.Server takes those photos and saves it to a network folder that points to a static file server.Testing with localhost everything works fine.However when using my phone connected to LAN, .write([]bytes) throws me an error Z:/xxx.jpg: The network connection was aborted by the local system.

I see that it did receive the bytes successfully checking with len([]bytes).Saving to local disk works fine.

I can not find a reason why that would happen.Since the program receives the bytes,how could it differentiate if they came from localhost or through another device?

Here is a snippet from my code

```
file, _, err := r.FormFile("uploadFile")
defer file.Close()
fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
filetype := http.DetectContentType(fileBytes)
switch filetype {
case "image/jpeg", "image/jpg":
case "image/gif", "image/png":
case "application/pdf":
    break
default:
    renderError(w, "INVALID_FILE_TYPE", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
fileName := randToken(12)
fileEndings, err := mime.ExtensionsByType(filetype)
if err != nil {
    renderError(w, "CANT_READ_FILE_TYPE", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    log.Print(err)
    return
}
newPath := uploadPath + fileName + fileEndings[0]
newFile, err := os.Create(newPath)
defer newFile.Close() 
if _, err := newFile.Write(fileBytes); err != nil || newFile.Close() != nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
}
//success
```

Comment: Is the value of `newPath` correct?  This is probably not the issue here, but the application should check and handle the error returned from os.Create before using `newFile`.

Comment: Yep it's correct.I do handle the err in my code which have never fired.It doees create the file with 0b size because it failes to write the bytes

Comment: Show the code that sets fileBytes.

Comment: @CeriseLimón hi,i updated my original post with the code.